# MeetingItem saved; but change now shown in Calendar

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I updated meeting item in Application_ItemSend event handler, the "sent" message shows the change; however on my calendar, the change doesn't show up.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect the change to show in the AppointmeentItem if you never modified it?

Have you tried to open the corresponding appointment using MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment and modify it as well?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, save the change to MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment, now my own calendar has the change.

Comment: This is to be expected. Again, why do you expect to see the change in the appointment item in your Calendar if you never modify it? You only modify the outgoing MeetingItem object.

Comment: My purpose is to add evaluation link to the meeting invitation. When people click on it all meeting information are already there. I want to see the link myself as well.